# Stack Editor issues on OS X latest (v10.14 (Mojave)) Chrome 70

Tags: support

This weekend I have several times lost the editor buttons and asked to prove I am not a robot (as if I had pasted my answer).
Is there an issue with the editor?

I see

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
>   cdn.sstatic.net/Js/post-validation.en.js?v=d4e9f25d6ecc:1 
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
>   cdn.sstatic.net/Js/external-editor.en.js?v=6db0df3b3951:1 
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Comment: Next time you see this, try loading https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/external-editor.en.js?v=6db0df3b3951:1 directly & see what you get

Comment: Mojave being a recent version of macOS for those who don't feel like looking it up :).

Comment: Updated title......